# Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Functions: observe child of user returns undefined when attempting event value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a user table in firebase real time database wit fields:

```
userKey
  - uid
  - emailVerfied
  - attempts
```

I would like to observe changes in `userKey/attempts` field, I have the following trigger setup:

```
 export const onUpdate = functions.database
.ref('/users/{uid}/attempts').onUpdate( event => {

    const record = event.after.val();

    // sending an email to myself, 
    adminLog(
          `user ${record.email} requested a new confirmation email`
        , `delivered from realtime.onUpdate with user ${record.uid}`);

})
```

This function is triggered each time the field `attempt` is updated, however it evidently cannot retrieve `record.uid` as I intended, because the email sent looks like this:

```
delivered from realtime.onUpdate with user undefined
```

What is the right way to retrieve a snapshot of the database' value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code and data structure, the value of `uid` in `'/users/{uid}/attempts'` will actually be `userKey`, and not the value of the sub-node `uid` of `userKey`.

And to get this value in your Cloud Function code you should do

```
 event.params.uid
```

since you are using a version of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions which is <1.0.0 (see below)

---

If, on the opposite, you want to get the value of `uid` and not the one of `userKey`, you should listen at the upper level, as follows:

```
export const onUpdate = functions.database.ref('/users/{userKey}').onUpdate(...)   //I just changed, for clarity, to userKey, instead of uid
```

I would then suggest that you upgrade your code to v1.0.0 (see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)) and then do as follows:

```
 functions.database.ref('/users/{userKey}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the update
  const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the update

  //You can then check if beforeData.attempts and afterData.attempts are different and act accordingly

  //You get the value of uid with: afterData.uid

  //You get the value of userKey (from the path) with: context.params.userKey

});
```

Comment: Is it possible to subscribe to changes to /users/{userKey}/attempts field only? That is the trigger should fire each time `attempts` change for every user? This way there's no need to check which field changed ...

Comment: Yes, follows the first part of my answer. But in this case you cannot get the value of uid, only the one of userKey. I make the assumption there are different.